# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [100, 300]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was learning KNN from udemy.
The dataset is downloaded from [here](https://sds-platform-private.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/P14-K-Nearest-Neighbors.zip).

When I try to run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4:].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train.ravel())

y_pred = classifier.predict(x_train)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

I got error as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/ashutosh/Machine Learning A-Z Template Folder/Part 3 - Classification/Section 15 - K-Nearest Neighbors (K-NN)/knn(1).py", line 24, in 
>       cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
>
> File "/home/ashutosh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 268, in confusion_matrix
>       y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
>
> File "/home/ashutosh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 80, in _check_targets
>       check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
>
> File "/home/ashutosh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
>       " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
>
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [100, 300]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_train)
```

to:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
```

and you're fine to go.